# Winsock client / server tutorial fails with desktop as client, but works with laptop as client

Tags: c++, winsock, winsock2

I have successfully built the client and server modules from the [Getting Started with Winsock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545(v=vs.85).aspx) tutorial.

I have a desktop and a laptop both connected to my wireless router – both running Windows 10.

---

Running the client module on the laptop, I am able to successfully transmit data back-and-forth to the desktop (running the server module) using the desktop's IP address.

---

Running the client module on the desktop with the laptop's IP address as the command line argument, I get an "Unable to connect to server!" message after a ten second delay.

If I try to run both modules on the desktop in separate console windows using the "localhost" command line argument, the client console displays "Bytes sent: 14" and hangs waiting for a response from the server – however this works if I use either the desktop name or the desktop IP address in place of "localhost".

I am able to run both modules on the laptop using either "localhost", the laptop name, or the laptop IP address as arguments.

---

I have gone through the same motions with port 27015 forwarded on the router and incoming and outgoing firewall exceptions added to both the desktop and the laptop – there is no difference either way.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as I cannot figure out why this works in one direction but not the other.

Comment: does the laptop have two network interfaces (e.g. cable+wifi)? Which address do you bind, i.e. what's the address in `result`?

Comment: Neither computer is connected to the router with a physical cable.  I'll need to add some code to the server module to have it display the bound address before it frees the result.  I can try that this evening and report back.

Comment: can you ping your laptop from your desktop?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: "It takes more energy to frown than it does to smile!"  "Yeah, well – you know it takes more energy to point that out than it does to leave me alone?"  -Bill Hicks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions Karsten and Andriy.  I first tried getting the two computers to ping each other and neither was successful.  After researching online, I was able to get them to ping after turning on "echo requests" in the firewall settings, but my original problem persisted.  I then tried turning off both firewalls and I was able to get my server and client programs to work both ways.  That wasn't a great long-term solution, so I tried selectively disabling the firewalls and realized it was an issue on the laptop's end.  I noticed that my "server.exe" program was in the allowed apps list twice – one instance granting private access and one granting public access – but only one instance was active.  I deleted both and added "server.exe" again with both public and private access boxes checked, which solved my issue.